# How can I define threshold in receiving requests by the pods(In Kubernetes environment)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have configured a cluster in Google Cloud Platform using KOPS. I used the "TCP LoadBalancer" option for exposing my services to public. In the current scenario,If a pod running in the cluster reached the maximum request,then the request is redirected to another pod which is in the same cluster. My question is Is it possible to manage or restrict the request handled by a pod,So that I can define a threshold in receiving requests by the pods.

Comment: I dont think the kubernetes service provides such mechanism on its own.  Kubernetes Service as far as i know only uses roundrobin.  Since you are using the LoadBalancer type, this is handled by your cloud provider's LB.

Comment: Thank you @BalChua for your comment.

Comment: According to @Nick it is not possible. An option to deploy an nginx ingress which supports rate limiting. 
 https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rate-limiting. But this is for the whole domain url not only pod.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do this. GCP does not provide this kind of metrics on load balancers. You may find information about something similar to what you want   in [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/).

> **Backend services**
>
> [Backend services](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service)  direct incoming traffic to one or more attached backends. Each backend  is composed of an  [instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups)  and  additional serving capacity metadata. Backend serving capacity can be  based on CPU or  [requests per second  (RPS)](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps#requests_per_second_rps).